# Flexible GUI web page to Excel using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-parts

I have a page created using Web Parts in `C#.NET 4.0`. It has a flexible UI and the user can change the position of the controls by dragging & dropping them. This page also has a functionality of ***"Export to Excel"*** in which the content of the page is exported to Excel.

As the layout of the page can be changed by the user so I cannot create a `HTML` Table from C# and export it to `Excel`. Can anyone suggest me a way to overcome this problem?

I want the excel to have the same positioning & content of the controls as it is currently visible to the user on the web page.

Comment: Just send that info to the server.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow your question, but if the issue is a question of layout (i.e. `<table>` isn't flexible enough), then use `<div>` with absolute positioning instead.

Comment: @SLaks: can you please elaborate on the approach you are telling to follow?

Comment: @JeffBridgman: I want the page layout in the exported excel similar to the web page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think I follow the question... also I'm not familiar with WebParts, so I might be missing something.